# trying to serialize and deserialize an xml file using VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

The xml file should like this after I serialize and then I want to deserialize this in vb.net. I am a begginer in programming. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Countries>
  <Country>
    <CID>1</CID>
    <CountryName>India</CountryName>
    <States>
      <State> New Delhi </State>
      <State> Maharashtra </State>
      <State> Rajasthan </State>
    </States>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    <States>
      <State> Washington </State>
      <State> Texas </State>
    </States>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <CID>3</CID>
    <CountryName>Australia</CountryName>
    <States>
      <State> Queensland </State>
      <State> Victoria </State>
    </States>
  </Country>
</Countries>
```

Comment: You should start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

Comment: is the purpose to save some data and reload or to export the data to a given file layout?

Comment: Do you have a data structure that needs to be serialized like this? Please share some VB.NET code. Do you need to serialize and also deserialize this XML?

Comment: @Neolisk i need a class structure that will be serialized into the above xml file and deserialize the xml to get back the original class structure. i am finding it difficult to get started

Comment: @subhrendu Look at my answer, it should get you started...

Comment: @Styxxy i also need the code for serializing into the xml file. xml file should look like d one i hve shown above. i hope you understand

Comment: @subhrendu I added the code for serialization. But really, you should try to find it yourself next time. It is all quite easy to find on the internet, by searching and/or reading the documentation.

Comment: @styxxy thanks a lot. it works. will be sure to do next time

Comment: @Styxxy offcourse i will mark it as an answer. just want to know if i wanted to add multiple state names under the same country tag what would i do.

Comment: @subhrendu Currently it is a list of strings, but you can change it to any type you want (and make sure that type can be serialized as well). You can make a `State` class, or it is possible to use an `Enum`. The answer is just a base, now you can apply the same technique to another class, or your own class definition(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd advise you to definitely look into XML serialization. A lot of information can be found on MSDN (but also using any search engine). For example on MSDN: [Introducing XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx).

If you have nothing yet, for code. I would keep it very simple to deserialize the given XML structure. You can create a simple class definition for a Country, as shown below:

```vb
Public Class Country
    Public Property CID As Integer
    Public Property CountryName As String
    Public Property States As List(Of String)

    Public Sub New()
        States = New List(Of String)()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now this doesn't work yet 100%. You have to help the serialization object with the list of states. You can annotate (with attributes) the `States`, so the serializer knows that each item is named differently (default it would be `<string>item</string>`). You can use the [`XmlArrayItem` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) for this.

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class Country
    Public Property CID As Integer
    Public Property CountryName As String
    <XmlArrayItem("State")>
    Public Property States As List(Of String)

    Public Sub New()
        States = New List(Of String)()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Finally, for deserialization. I'd deserialize to a `List(Of Country)`, as it clearly is a list. (Assuming the above XML is stored in a file "obj.xml".)

```vb
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Country)))
Dim deserialized As List(Of Country) = Nothing
Using file = System.IO.File.OpenRead("obj.xml")
    deserialized = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(file), List(Of Country))
End Using
```

Now we still have to help the serializer object, because otherwise it doesn't know how to deserialize the given XML; as it doesn't determine the root node correctly. We can use an overload of the constructor here, in which we can say what the root node is ([`XmlSerializer Constructor (Type, XmlRootAttribute)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys.aspx)).

Final code for deserialization would be:

```vb
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Country)), New XmlRootAttribute("Countries"))
Dim deserialized As List(Of Country) = Nothing
Using file = System.IO.File.OpenRead("obj.xml")
    deserialized = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(file), List(Of Country))
End Using
```

Code for serialization (writing to file "obj.xml"):

```vb
Dim countries As New List(Of Country)()
' Make sure you add the countries to the list

Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Country)), New XmlRootAttribute("Countries"))
Using file As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open("obj.xml", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
    serializer.Serialize(file, countries)
End Using
```

All this could have been found quite easily by searching and reading the documentation.