# Display a list of string in a textbox in SSRS

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've been working on reports using SQL Server Reporting Services and I've come with a problem.

I have a report that contains multiple datasets. Let's say I have those datasets:

- DatasetPotatoes
- DatasetUnicorns
- DatasetJobs

My report is using a XML to get the value of my fields. Let's say my XML is the following :

```
<XML>
    <Jobs>
        <string>Job1</string>
        <string>Job2</string>
        <string>Job3</string>
    </Jobs>
    <Potatoes>
        <id>123</id>
        <fieldname>blabla</fieldname>
    </Potatoes>
</XML>
```

I'd like to be able to put in a single textbox all the values of my List(Of String) (so all my `<string>` values) are like that : Job1, Job2, Job3.

Here is an example of how my textbox are populated using an expression:

```
=First(Fields!fieldname.Value, "DatasetPotatoes")
```

Do you know if it's possible to get all my `<string></string>` values? Or a least get an array of my `<string></string>` values so I can format it using VB.NET code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to serialize and deserialize an xml file using VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246002/trying-to-serialize-and-deserialize-an-xml-file-using-vb-net)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem isn't about the tag "string" itself, but about joining all string values in one single textbox.

Comment: Since I can't edit for 5 minutes, here is another answer.
Here is the mapping of the field :

    =RunningValue(Code.ConcatenerString(Fields!string.Value),Max,"ObjetProtectionsDemandees")

Here is the little homemade function:

    Dim test as String = String.Empty
Function ConcatenerString(_string as String) As String
test = test & _string & ","
Return test 
End Function    

Since it's working, I wonder if it's dangerous to use it, it looks like a shared variable, so it could be dangerous to make other reports at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a parameter using a query/dataset that defaults and available to all of the values/items you wish to be shown together in one field.

on the report insert a field and set the expression to be :

```
=join(Parameters!Parameters.Value, " , " )
```

View the report and all of the items will appear in a single field.

Comment: Add some explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is useful for someone: if you need this outside any data region, and you do not want to create a parameter, this way works for me:

```
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!Name.Value,"SalesMen"),", ")
```

I use it because I think it is clearer than using a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So for this you want to do the following

1. create a new data set.
2. add the parameter.
3. on the report insert a field and set the expression to be :

```
=join(Parameters!Parameters.Value, " , " )
```