# How to deserialize 5-6 level tags using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
<world> 
    <apac>
        <sasia> 
            <india>
                <sindia>
                    <tn>CHENNAI
                    <tn>Madurai





    <apac>
        <sasia> 
            <india>
                <sindia>
                    <ka>Bangalore
                    <ka>Mysore
```

When I try 4 level tag its works, but for 5 level tag it doesn't help.

I've tried: 
[trying to serialize and deserialize an xml file using VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246002/trying-to-serialize-and-deserialize-an-xml-file-using-vb-net)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686509/trouble-serializing-and-deserializing-multiple-objects/58687570#58687570) will give you some hints.

Comment: Is that really what the xml looks like? You have no closing tags. If so, then xml serialization will not work! If you have a valid xml file, please put a real example in your question, otherwise we can't accurately help you.

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074005/saving-listbox-with-additional-information-in-my-settings/59097544#59097544) vb.net version. Still hot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your xml has properly closed tags etc.,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<world>
  <apac>
    <sasia>
      <india>
        <sindia>
          <tn>CHENNAI</tn>
          <tn>Madurai</tn>
        </sindia>
      </india>
    </sasia>
  </apac>
  <apac>
    <sasia>
      <india>
        <sindia>
          <ka>Bangalore</ka>
          <ka>Mysore</ka>
        </sindia>
      </india>
    </sasia>
  </apac>
</world>
```

here are some classes you can use to define your model

```vb
<XmlRoot("world")>
Public Class World
    <XmlElement("apac")>
    Public Property Apacs As List(Of Apac)
End Class
Public Class Apac
    <XmlElement("sasia")>
    Public Property Sasia As Sasia
End Class
Public Class Sasia
    <XmlElement("india")>
    Public Property India As India
End Class
Public Class India
    <XmlElement("sindia")>
    Public Property Sindia As Sindia
End Class
Public Class Sindia
    <XmlElement("ka")>
    Public Property Kas As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("tn")>
    Public Property Tns As List(Of String)
End Class
```

and code you can use to deserialize

```vb
Dim myWorld As World
Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(World))
Using sr As New StreamReader("filename.xml")
    myWorld = DirectCast(s.Deserialize(sr), World)
End Using
```

and code you can test it with.

```vb
Console.WriteLine(myWorld.Apacs.First().Sasia.India.Sindia.Tns.First())
Console.WriteLine(myWorld.Apacs.Last().Sasia.India.Sindia.Kas.First())
```

> CHENNAI
>   Bangalore

Of course, if you xml doesn't look like this (I must admit I did some guesswork), then this code won't work. If you must, update your question by closing xml tags when required and we can work on the right solution.