# Saving ListBox with Additional information in My.settings

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I recently started learning listboxes on VB.net and wanted to create something like a student list with additional information:

```
Private Class Students
    Private m_Name As String
    Private m_Age As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal new_Name As String, ByVal new_Age As String)
        m_Name = new_Name
        m_Age = new_Age
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return m_Name
    End Function

    Public Function Age() As String
        Return m_Age
    End Function
End Class
```

So, students add to the listbox as follows:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(New Students(StudentName.Text, StudentAge.Text)) 
'StudentName and  StudentAge are textboxes.
```

but I also wanted to save this information so that it is automatically entered when the program is restarted. I tried to do first an event that saves every item in the ListBox but using the function above it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        My.Settings.Students.Add(item)
        My.Settings.Save()
    Next
End Sub
```

Then I would like to load this information, but just like the event with saving information when closing the program it does not work.

I got an `System.InvalidCastException The conversion of 'Students' to 'String' is not valid.` error.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.Students Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.Students = New Specialized.StringCollection
    Else
        For Each item In My.Settings.Students
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like to have these the information in listbox after load.

Comment: `My.Settings` isn't really the best way of storing data that contains more than one value per entry. Serialization is much more suitable for this. May I ask why you don't want to store your data in a file that you have more control over? (for the record, `My.Settings` is also stored in a file in XML format, located somewhere in %LocalAppData%)

Comment: For security reasons, but as I think about it now, it can be saved as a file. But that doesn't change the fact that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: 1) Note that listboxes are a part of Winforms, which is a part of .NET. They can be used from VB.NET or from C#, or from any other language that supports .NET. It's important to realize this, because generally information on interacting with Winforms might be of value to you, even if it's written in a different .NET language. 2) It might be a good idea to clarify what you mean by _it does not work._ -- is there some kind of exception? the settings are not being retrieved?

Comment: "It does not work" means entirely too many different things.  One obvious bug is that the FormClosing event handler adds items to the collection that are already present in the collection.  Another is that My.Settings uses XML serialization, the class does not support that.  Google "vb.net make object xml serializable" to get ahead.

Comment: `System.InvalidCastException The conversion of 'Students' to 'String' is not valid.`

Comment: It would also be helpful to identify at which line the exception occurs.

Comment: If you want security why not store you data in a nice secure database. XML files are human readable.

Comment: I would have thought that age would be an Integer but don't store age anyway. It could change the very next day. Store date of birth as a Date and calculate age when needed. Your Student class has not a single property!

Comment: Create an extension to your class where you will binary serialize it and save using `File.WriteAllBytes`. Then, when you need it, read the file and deserialize into instance.

Comment: Lookup Binary Serialization or XML Serialization. Either is very easy to implement and make saving/loading classes simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[My.Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object) is a feature that enables you to manage your application's settings such as; the last location and size of a form, the last selected properties of controls, recently opened files, ...etc. It's not - as already commented above - a place to store and retrieve your objects' data. Your data should be in a database or serialized as an alternative. Let's try the serialization approach to solve your problem.

**Create your Serializable objects**

- The `Student` class:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

<Serializable()>
Public Class Student

#Region "Enums"

    <Serializable()>
    Public Enum Genders
        Unknown
        Female
        Male
    End Enum

#End Region

#Region "Constructors"

    Public Sub New() : End Sub

    Public Sub New(firstName As String, lastName As String, dob As DateTime, gender As Genders)
        Me.FirstName = firstName
        Me.LastName = lastName
        Me.DOB = dob
        Me.Gender = gender
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Public Properties"

    Public Property FirstName As String

    Public Property LastName As String

    Public ReadOnly Property FullName As String
        Get
            Return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property DOB As DateTime

    Public ReadOnly Property Age As Integer
        Get
            If DOB = Nothing Then Return 0

            Dim y As Integer = Today.Year - DOB.Year

            If DOB > Today.AddYears(-y) Then y -= 1

            Return y
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Gender As Genders

#End Region

#Region "Public Methods"

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{FullName}, {Age}, {Gender}"
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

- The `Students` class:

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class Students

#Region "Public Properties"

    Public Property List As New List(Of Student)

#End Region

#Region "Public Functions"

    Public Sub SaveXml(filePath As String)
        Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Students))

        Try
            Using fs As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
                xs.Serialize(fs, Me)
            End Using
        Catch ex As SerializationException
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize!")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function LoadXml(filePath As String) As Students
        Dim students As Students = Nothing

        Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Students))

        Try
            Using fs As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
                students = DirectCast(xs.Deserialize(fs), Students)
            End Using
        Catch ex As SerializationException
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize!")
        End Try

        Return students
    End Function

    'Or if you prefer the binary format.
    Public Sub SaveBytes(filePath As String)
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter

        Try
            Using fs As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
                bf.Serialize(fs, Me)
            End Using
        Catch ex As SerializationException
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize!")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function LoadBytes(filePath As String) As Students
        Dim students As Students = Nothing
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter

        Try
            Using fs As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
                students = DirectCast(bf.Deserialize(fs), Students)
            End Using
        Catch ex As SerializationException
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize!")
        End Try

        Return students
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

**Your new classes in action!**

In your form which contains the `ListBox`, create a class level variable of [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.8) type which will be used to populate the list box, add, edit, and remove `Student` objects.

```vb
Private bs As BindingSource
```

In your Form's constructor or `Load` event, load or create a new object of `Students` type, create a new instance of the `BindingSource` and attach it to the ListBox's `DataSource` property as follow:

```vb
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.MyStudentsFile) Then
    'XML file.
    My.Settings.MyStudentsFile = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "MyStudentsData.xml")
    'or a binary file name if you prefer the binary formatter, for example.
    'My.Settings.MyStudentsFile = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "MyStudentsData.dat")
End If

If File.Exists(My.Settings.MyStudentsFile) Then
    obj = Students.LoadXml(My.Settings.MyStudentsFile)
    'or
    'obj = Students.LoadBytes(My.Settings.MyStudentsFile)
End If

If obj Is Nothing Then obj = New Students

bs = New BindingSource(obj, "List")

ListBox1.DataSource = bs
```

Where the `My.Settings.MyStudentsFile` is the path of the data file.

What will be displayed in the list box is what the `ToString` returns for each `Student` object. If you'd like instead to display the `FullName` only, then set the `DisplayMember` property of the list box as follow:

```vb
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName"
```

To add new `Student`:

```vb
Dim stu As New Student(
    "FirstName",
    "LastName",
    New DateTime(2000, 5, 22),
    Student.Genders.Male
)
bs.Add(stu)
ListBox1.ClearSelected()
ListBox1.SelectedItem = stu
```

To modify the properties of a `Student` entry:

```vb
If bs.Current IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim stu As Student = DirectCast(bs.Current, Student)

    stu.FirstName = "CorrectFirstName"
    stu.LastName = "CorrectLastName"
    stu.Gender = Student.Genders.Female

    bs.ResetCurrentItem()
End If
```

To remove entries:

```vb
If bs.Current IsNot Nothing Then
    bs.RemoveCurrent()
End If

'In case of multixxx SelectionMode
ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of Student).ToList.ForEach(Sub(stu) bs.Remove(stu))
```

To display a selected item in other controls, handle the `SelectedValueChanged` event of the list box as follow:

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    If bs.Current IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim stu As Student = DirectCast(bs.Current, Student)

        TextBox1.Text = stu.FirstName
        TextBox2.Text = stu.LastName
        DateTimePicker1.Value = If(stu.DOB <> Nothing, stu.DOB, Now)
        TextBox3.Text = stu.Age.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, to save your data in `Form.FormClosing` event:

```vb
bs.EndEdit()

Dim stus As Students = DirectCast(bs.DataSource, Students)

stus.SaveXml(My.Settings.MyStudentsFile)
'or
'stus.SaveBytes(My.Settings.MyStudentsFile)

bs.Dispose()
```

That's it all.

Comment: Maybe i'm doing it wrong but `System.ArgumentException: An empty path name is not allowed.` at XML Saving function

Comment: @uloy Check the update. The code of the constructor or Load event.