# How to copy text from multiple textboxes into one single text file. And can be entered multiple times into same text file

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program named E-GRADES, and I would like to know how I can make the text from 3 textboxes get copied into a text file in a specific folder. And so that for every student. I want to enter new grades, subjects and description on what it is for example:

```
Grade : 5,
Description : Exam,
Subject : English,
```

and that it doesn't have to make a new file every time a new grade is entered. I want text file to look like this

```
Grade : 5,
Description : Exam,
Subject : English,

Grade : 5,
Description : Exam,
Subject : Maths,
```

I hope you can help me! Btw if you have time, can you explain how to make that teachers can enter their own students.

Comment: Hi @Hystel. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your question and add the code that you have written so far. Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suggest that your use a database for this program. There are several free ones available. When you want to use the data you have inputted it will be far easier with a database.

Comment: Break this down into steps. 1. Retrieve the values from the TextBoxes. 2. Build a string from the values. 3. Append the text to a file. Hint: `File.AppendAllText()` in `System.IO`.

Comment: I'd follow @Mary 's suggestion and the popular [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) is an example. However, if the Database isn't an option for now, then consider objects [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) as an accepted alternative for applications as such. You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074005/saving-listbox-with-additional-information-in-my-settings/59097544#59097544) example and extend it.